# Game Center even without itunes connect

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

is it possible to insert a leaderboard using gamecenter in my app even if i dont have itunes connect??

what can be possibly done if not?

*i have searched in google for days but none satisfied me.*

thanks =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Center uses the configuration data in iTunes Connect for it's leader boards, there is no other valid way to create them.

Comment: Seems that way - bit confused as how you have access to the developer stuff but not iTunes connect. For alternative leaderboards (which are also cross platform, something game connect will never be) check out OpenFeint: http://www.openfeint.com/

Comment: thanks but openfeint's documentation and tutorials are really not nice... besides i have tried that already i am getting errors in OpenFeintPrefix.pch i tried all the solutions by googling however when i searched the entire openfeint folder the OpenFeintPrefix wasn't really there. thats why i didn't tried it anymore.

Comment: Hmmm, see if you can disable precompiled headers for it, sounds like that's causing you a problem somehow.

Comment: is it possible? because i have tried deleting the OpenFeintPrefix import. then i got about 60+ errors i guess